# Error when using BAT Files. - R was unexpected at this time

Tags: batch-file, cmd

**This is code:**

```
call n:\xxx\xxx\variables.bat %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6

set yourZipPassword=%xxx%
set yourFolderPath="n:\xxxx\xxxx\%xxxx%"

for /R "%yourFolderPath%" %%I in ("*.zip") do (
  "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" x -p%yourZipPassword% -y -o"%%~dpI" "%%~fI" 
)
```

Do not know what to do with this error - "**R was unexpected at this time.**"

And this bat file stuck on this line and not processing anymore:

```
for /R "%yourFolderPath%" %%I in ("*.zip") do (
```

Comment: @aschipfl  please check my additional question, if you know the answer. (Can post every 90 min, but need help now.)

Comment: Please *never* add different questions to existing question posts, because this makes all current answers incomplete or even obsolete! Always post them as a *new question* instead! Anyway, there is no quick answer for the new issue like there was for the original post; you need to define precisely how the `BLABLA` part can be extracted, and you need to show some efforts on your own; there are already a lot of posts for a [similar task](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbatch-file%5D+file+rename)...

Comment: @aschipfl Ok, I will not)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the `set` syntax from...:

```
set yourFolderPath="n:\xxxx\xxxx\%xxxx%"
```

...to the following (in general):

```
set "yourFolderPath=n:\xxxx\xxxx\%xxxx%"
```

So the quotes are no longer part of the value. As you have it in your question, the `for /R` loop (`for /R "%yourFolderPath%"`) receives a root path like `for /R ""n:\xxxx\xxxx\%xxxx%""`, so it is "over-quoted". This constitutes a problem particularly in case there are white-spaces and/or special characters in the variable value.

---

The changed `set` syntax has got another advantage: Imagine you have a variable holding a directory path and another one holding a file name, using the syntax from your question:

```
set PDIR="D:\Data"
set FILE="file.ext"
```

Now let us concatenate these values:

```
echo unquoted: %PDIR%\%FILE%
echo quoted: "%PDIR%\%FILE%"
```

The returned lines were:

> ```
> unquoted: "D:\Data"\"file.ext"
> quoted: ""D:\Data"\"file.ext""
> ```

You can see there are some disturbing quotes. Now let us use the changed syntax:

```
set "PDIR=D:\Data"
set "FILE=file.ext"

echo unquoted: %PDIR%\%FILE%
echo quoted: "%PDIR%\%FILE%"
```

So the returned lines were:

> ```
> unquoted: D:\Data\file.ext
> quoted: "D:\Data\file.ext"
> ```

So there are no more disturbing quotes.

---

Note that the changed syntax only works with [command extensions enabled](http://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html), but this is the default setting for the Windows command prompt `cmd` anyway.