# Batch: Reading in a line from a file that has a colon and exclamation

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to read a line from a file that contains a colon and exclamation point. When I echo that line, it only shows everything AFTER the colon. I need to keep the `enabledelayedexpansion` for more advanced code I will be doing in the do loop. But right now I just want to echo properly.

The file should say something like this:

```
! 12345 APX:
6.32
```

The code I tried was:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
cd C:\Users\jwagh\Desktop\
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in (test.txt) DO (
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
 echo %%a
 set line=%%a
 set example=%line:~0,-1%
 echo %example%
)
```

Comment: Disable delayed expansion during expansion of `%%a`, and enable it only when you really need it...

Comment: I tried re-enabling it within the do-loop and it doesn't work.

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not a quite precise description, is it? Perhaps you should post a bit more code, so it might be easier to help you. In general, you need to regard the environment localisation of `setlocal`/`endlocal`, and you need to know that the nesting level of such blocks is limited, hence you need an `endlocal` within the loop when you have a `setlocal` there...

Comment: That's because you need to **DIS**abledelayedexpansion within your `DO`.

Comment: updated code. Does not work.

Comment: @Wajo357, now it becomes clearer; anyway, I posted an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41388147) meanwhile, which might help...

Comment: Don't edit your question with suggestions provided in comment. Your most recent edit no longer gives the symptoms you describe in the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably disabling delayedexpansion is the only practicable solution, but depending on your data, setting `delims` to `!` would set `%%a` to the entire line, minus the initial `!` (assuming obviously only one `!`-sequence of known length and it always leads the line)

OR

```
for /f "usebackq delims=!" %%a in (%FamilyFile%) DO echo ^^!%%a
```

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The only bullet-proof solution is to disable [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) during expansion of `%%a`, and to enable it only when it is actually needed. For example, something like this:

```cmd
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in (%File%) do (
    set "Item=%%a"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    echo(!Item:,-1!
    endlocal
)
```

Since localised environments created by [`setlocal`](http://ss64.com/nt/setlocal.html)/[`endlocal`](http://ss64.com/nt/endlocal.html) blocks are limited in terms of nesting, you need to put also `endlocal` within a loop. Regard that after `endlocal`, all environment changes since the latest `setlocal` get lost.

---

But now for something completely different (related to [revision 3](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/41387723/3) of the question):
I assume `%File%` holds a quoted file path/name, because of the `usebackq` option.
Let me recommend not to include the quotes in the variable value, using the following syntax:

```cmd
set "File=D:\Data\file.ext"  & rem // (particularly note the position of the opening quote)
```

Reference [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40805335) to learn why this is better.